# Java Jersey 2.27 ServletException in basic example

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jersey, servlet-3.0

**Is something wrong with web.xml? 
I am not using maven here I created dynamic web app using eclipse , tomcat 8.5,** **jersey 2.27**

***Please first have look on my web.xml ? Am i not using correct servlet class and init-param in web.xml? My problem is not just Exception I am not sure about web.xml***

resulting in following errors:

**http status: 500**

**javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [jersey-servlet] threw exception.**

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Providers**

Below is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>RestWebService</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.swapnil.webservice</param-value>
        </init-param>

    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

My java class:

```
package com.swapnil.webservice;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("*/helloWorld")
public class HelloRestService {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("name")
    public String getGreeting(@Context HttpHeaders httpHeaders, @PathParam("name") String name) {
        String greeting = "Hello" + name;
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

[image: Resulting exception]

Comment: Problem is not just exception. Please review my web.xml file  and let me know whether i am using correct <servlet-class>  and <init-param> in web.xml or not